# Asymptotic limit of derivative of a uni-variate function is positive. Can I conclude there is no global maxima?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Further, assume $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) >0$. Is it true that there is no global maxima for this function? That is, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\exists y\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)<f(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=L$, and take $N$ such that, if $x>N$, $f'(x)\geq\frac L2$ – the existence of such a number is direct from epsilon-delta. Therefore, for $x\geq N$, $$f(x)\geq f(N)+(x-N)\cdot\frac L2$$ by the MVT, and we're done, since $f$ attains arbitrarily large values.